# edit in IDLE not working in a specific folder

Tags: python, windows

I've ran into a weird problem.
So I've created a folder on my desktop that contains a couple 10-20 line codes that I'm testing things out with. Recently I tried to open one with *right click -> edit with idle*. After that nothing happens. I can still open the codes by opening an empty shell first and then go to *file-> open*.

I can also move my codes to another folder or even a folder inside the problem folder, and *right click -> edit with idle* would work fine again. As soon as I move the files back into the problem folder, things stop working.

Double clicking the files would also open the console window and execute the codes as normal.

It certainly wasn't always like this, and I don't believe that I have done anything that would cause this, any ideas why this is happening?

Greatly appreciate all of your feedback.

Comment: You don't have an `idle.py` file in that folder, do you?

Comment: No, I definitely don't, but I did solve the issue. I deleted a code that I was testing threading with and that fixed the issue, not sure why that is.

Comment: Then you should leave an answer so future visitors with the same problem can gain from your hard work and suffering.

Answer (score 0):

A file named `types.py` (e.g. empty) in the folder causes that exact problem under python 3.11.4

Moving or renaming that file solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I named one of the files configparser.py, which is a standard module. After I removed this, everything started as it should. So be careful when naming your files.